# DocuSign for Salesforce - Signing Order is ignored

Tags: javascript, docusign

I want to integrate Salesforce with Docusign. However, I'm struggling with something as simple as the signing order.
For testing purposes, I made my custom button as simple as possible:

```js
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '', RSL='',  RSRO='', RROS='', CCRM='',
    CCTM='', CCNM='', CRCL='', CRL='',  OCO='',
    DST='',  LA='',   CEM='',  CES='',  STB='',
    SSB='',  SES='',  SEM='',  SRS='',  SCS ='', RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 

// Docs: https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-customize-envelope-contacts

// Adding Notes & Attachments 
LA='0'; 

// Custom Recipient Contact List 
var 
  recip1 = "Email~recip1@acme.com;" +
           "LastName~Recip1;" + 
           "RoutingOrder~2;",
  recip2 = "Email~recip2@acme.com;" +
           "LastName~Recip2;" +
           "RoutingOrder~1"; 

CRL = recip1 + "," + recip2;

//Custom Envelop from Docusign 
DST='9c448207-13ed-4933-8217-89a5dc5bec02'; 

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href =
  "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&"
  +"SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC
  +"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM
  +"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO
  +"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES
  +"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES
  +"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

As shown in `Screenshot 1`, the template is correctly selected and the signing order for the recipients is respected:

[image: Screenshot 1]

However, clicking `Send Now` will ignore the signing order. If I click `Next` and then `Edit Recipients` in the next screen, one can see that the signing order is ignored:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Additionally predefining the signing order in the template is not a viable solution either - my number of recipients will change dependent on the Salesforce record I am on. Also, I noticed issues with custom anchor tags when predefining recipients in a template. E.g. `\s2\` will be merged for Signer 2, but `\tbx_2_title\` will be merged for Signer 1.

Edit: It seems that when I do not use template preselection, the signing order is preserved. But requiring the user to manually select the template and adding the mergefields manually is not a viable solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard anchor tags are being assigned by the order you have the roles in your Salesforce DocuSign Admin

**Example:**

Signer 1

Signer 2

Signer 3

However, the custom anchor tag that I created in DocuSign are being assigned by how I have the roles set up in the template

**Example:**

Signer 2

Signer 3

Signer 1

Apparently, DocuSign is working on fixing this. Not relying on the automatic anchor text placing and instead manually placing them on the layout fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

Try switching places of signers inside `CRL` variable.

Example:

```
CRL = recip2 + "," + recip1;
```